# Chrome devtools can't simulate push event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, service-worker

I have this code in the service worker:

```
self.addEventListener('push', e => {
  console.log('Evento: Push')

  let title = 'Push Notificación Demo',
    options = {
      body: 'Click para regresar a la aplicación',
      icon: './img/icon_192x192.png',
      vibrate: [100, 50, 100],
      data: { id: 1 },
      actions: [
        { 'action': 'Si', 'title': 'Amo esta aplicación :)', icon: './img/icon_192x192.png' },
        { 'action': 'No', 'title': 'No me gusta esta aplicación :(', icon: './img/icon_192x192.png' }
      ]
    }

  e.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options))
})

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', e => {
  console.log(e)

  if (e.action === 'Si') {
    console.log('AMO esta aplicación')
    clients.openWindow('https://ed.team')
  } else if (e.action === 'No') {
    console.log('No me gusta esta aplicación')
  }

  e.notification.close()
})
```

But the chrome devtools cannot simulate the event push. I've click the option called "Push" Which is in the application tab...

[image: DEVTOOLS CAPTURE]

But it doesn't work

How can i simulate the push?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Update your version of Chrome to 72 or up, the push will work.

Comment: Update? The question I did is a bug?

Comment: @AndrésMontoya for some reason in the previous versions of Chrome simulate the push didn't work. When you update to last version the problem go away.

Comment: If you test the push in firefox browser you can check that event is arriving with null value.

Comment: Thanks for your help!